# Error: ld: warning: ignoring file libfile01.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): libfile01.a

Tags: ios, iphone, c, native, arm7

I'm trying to compile a project developed in C language for iOS devices. It uses custom library file, libcurl, libcrypto, libssl and libpthread. I have successfully compiled it for Mac OS X, but having issues compiling it for iOS. Also, any help I try to find online is more of Xcode GUI help, and I need command line help for it. Need to compile it through commands instead of Xcode GUI.

First it needs to compile couple of C files, then make a static library file out of these compiled files, which further used when compiling a native binary.

---

This is how I generated iOS arm ouptut files from c files inside file01:

Store the iphoneos sdk path in environemnt variable:

```
CC="$(xcrun --sdk iphoneos9.2 --find clang) -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos9.2 --show-sdk-path) -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -arch armv6 -arch arm64"
```

Compile the c files in file01 with command:
`$CC -c -O2 *.c`

To check which architect these files are compiled for can be checked with this `lipo` command. Example:

```
$ lipo -info example_file01.o 
Architectures in the fat file: example_file01.o are: armv7 armv7s armv6 arm64
```

To make a static library file I can get iOS `ar` file path using command:

```
$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos9.2 --find ar /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar
```

I could store the path in an environment variable, but it was not working throwing error not recognising `ar` command arguments `rcu`. So, used the `ar` path instead to create the library file with this command:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar rcu ../output/libfile01.a *.o
```

If checking which architectures this lib file supports it gives this output:

```
$ lipo -info ../output/libfile01.a 
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: archive with no architecture specification: ../output/libfile01.a (can't determine architecture for it)
```

But, it should have given output similar to this one:

```
$ lipo -info ../ios/lib/libcurl.a 
Architectures in the fat file: ../ios/lib/libcurl.a are: i386 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64
```

This is causing error when trying compiling files in using the generated static lib file with command:

```
$CC -o ../output/FinalProjectFile -O2 *.c ../output/libfile01.a ../ios/lib/libcurl.a ../ios/lib/libssl.a ../ios/lib/libcrypto.a -lpthread -lm

Error: ​ld: warning: ignoring file ../output/libfile01.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): ../output/libfile01.a​
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Okay, can anybody at least tell how can I compile a collection of C program as a static .a library file, which I could use for iOS device ? I can build the same for OS X using this command `gcc -c  -O2 *.c jpeg/*.c jpeg/unix/*.c && ar rcu ../agents/libcrypto777.a *.o` but it doesn't work for iOS, and I get the problem explained in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by using different argument for `ar`.

Instead of using

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar rcu ../output/libfile01.a *.o
```

used

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar -rcs ../output/libfile01.a *.o
```

The only difference was it's `-rcs` instead of `rcu`.

When checking the info of this libfile it shows the output like this:

```
$ lipo -info ../output/libfile01.a 
Architectures in the fat file: ../output/libfile01.a are: armv7 armv7s armv6 arm64
```